# Why does 'error 2003 (timed out)' appear on my Python-Flask application? MySQL-Docker

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, docker, flask

I've been trying to develop an API using Python-Flask and a MySQL Docker container in AWS. The following error appears when I try to access my endpoints: `(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '54.204.79.149' (timed out)")`. What I find odd is that a couple of days ago the endpoints worked fine and I even tested them on Postman, so I know the mistake is not there.

#### What appears on the terminal:

```
* Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.     
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.     
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8001
 * Running on http://10.100.241.223:8001 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
(2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '54.204.79.149' (timed out)")
```

What appears on Chrome: `{"message": "Internal Server Error"}`

#### The `app.py` setup:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)

mysql = MySQL()

api = Api(app)

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = '1234'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'llevame_pe'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = '54.204.79.149'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PORT'] = 8005

mysql.init_app(app)

.
.
.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8001, debug=False)
```

#### The MySQL container is running on AWS:

```
docker run -d --rm --name mysql_c -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=1234 -p 8005:3306 -v mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql mysql:8.0

docker run -d --rm --name adminer_c -p 8080:8080 adminer
```

`docker ps -a` confirms that both containers are running:

```
:~ $ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE       COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                  NAMES
16c7bb3f53aa   adminer     "entrypoint.sh docke…"   23 minutes ago   Up 23 minutes   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp              adminer_c
4d32238f6c39   mysql:8.0   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   37 minutes ago   Up 37 minutes   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8005->3306/tcp, :::8005->3306/tcp   mysql_c
```

All database credentials look fine, and all the ports used are open in the virtual machine. The problem might be related to the firewall in MySQL but I'm not sure how that works.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Perhaps your database server was temporarily down.  It seems to be responding right now.

Comment: The database itself seems to work fine, as I can access it through Adminer. However, the problem continues on the Flask app.